# How to reduce space between ggplot and next text when using grid.arrange?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Consider the following R markdown page

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
require(ggplot2)
require(data.table)
require(gridExtra)
require(knitr)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, include=FALSE}
df <- data.table(x1=rnorm(n = 100), x2=rnorm(100))
```

Here is a plot

```{r,echo=FALSE, out.width='\\textwidth'}
hist1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x1)) +
  geom_histogram()

hist2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x2)) +
  geom_histogram()

grid.arrange(hist1, hist2, ncol=2, heights=c(10,10))
```

Some more text....
````

When I plot the two histograms `hist1` and `hist2` with `grid.arrange()` of the `gridExtra` package I find the plots too large, I want to reduce the height.

The `heights` parameter in `grid.arrange()` does reduce the height but it leaves a bit whitespace between the plot and the next text.
How can I reduce the height without getting that whitespace?

Comment: Can you include the YAML and an image of the output? I guess being knitted to a PDF but it would help to clarify these details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rmarkdown we can set the figure sizes in the chunk options.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, out.width='\\textwidth', message=FALSE, fig.height=3, fig.width=6, fig.align="center"}
df <- data.table(x1=rnorm(100), x2=rnorm(100))
hist1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x1)) + geom_histogram()
hist2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x2)) + geom_histogram()
grid.arrange(hist1, hist2, ncol=2)
```

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod 
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
````

***YIelding***

[image]

***Note:*** See a summary of other chunk options [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/r-code.html).